# Get h1 content and put into variable

Tags: wordpress, get

In my wordpress I've got a post:

```
<h1 id="rozdzial_1">Tytul rozdzialu</h1>
Some txt
<!--nextpage-->
<h1 id="rozdzial_2">Kolejny tytul</h1>
Some txt
<!--nextpage-->
<h1 id="rozdzial_3">Jeszcze jeden</h1>
Some txt
```

The content of this post is in get_the_content()

How to get from this content all the values of H1 and put it into variables?
The H1 with id = rozdzial_1 to a variable rozdzial_1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dom parser (best option).
Or simply a regexp, like this :

```
$content = get_the_content();

if (preg_match_all('#<h1 id="(.*)">(.*)</h1>#i', $content, $matches))
{
    foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$val)
    {
        $$val = $matches[2][$key];
    }
}

// test
echo $rozdzial_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PHP Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
<?php
    $content = get_the_content();
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->LoadHTML($content);

    $items = $DOM.getElementsByTagName('h1');


    /* post all h1 elements, now you can do the same with getElementsByID to get the id's with that you expect. */
    for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }
?>
```